# Why are some parts of Boost and other libraries (like Folly) in the detail subfolder?

Tags: c++, boost, build, compilation

What is the reason for separating parts of implementation into a separate `.h`/`.cpp` file? I understand that changing headers forces recompilation, but what is the benefit of moving the implementation to a separate `.cpp`?

Facebook does this with Folly https://github.com/facebook/folly/tree/master/folly/detail, Boost does this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The stuff in the `detail` namespace is usually supporting template code (which therefore can't go in a separate translation unit) but is not considered to be part of the *public* interface.

So the objects and functions are put there to be 'out of the way', and make it clear they're undocumented.

They are the parts of the code which you the library consumer should not concern yourself with since they are likely to change in a new version of the library.